# decision_function in example of scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I can't understand the code. What does it doing?

```
clf.decision_function([[1]])
```

I read `scikit-learn.org` and I couldn't understand it.

```
X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
Y = [0, 1, 2, 3]
clf = svm.SVC(gamma='scale', decision_function_shape='ovo')
clf.fit(X, Y) 
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
    decision_function_shape='ovo', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
    max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
    tol=0.001, verbose=False)
dec = clf.decision_function([[1]])
dec.shape[1] # 4 classes: 4*3/2 = 6
6
clf.decision_function_shape = "ovr"
dec = clf.decision_function([[1]])
dec.shape[1] # 4 classes
4
```

Comment: What language is this? Python? Which version of Python?

Comment: Could you add the exact link where you got this example from?

Comment: This is Python.    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

Comment: `The decision_function method of SVC and NuSVC gives per-class scores for each sample (or a single score per sample in the binary case)` . the formula shape gives you always the dimension of a array/dataframe (in this case length)